# How to make website menu dropdown on hover rather than click

Tags: html, css, drupal-8

Looking for some help.  I'm helping to upgrade a website from Drupal 7 to 8.
One of the problems I cannot resolve is how to make the drop-down menus display when you hover over them.

You can see how it works on the live site here:
https://eerr.org.uk/

And how it does not work here:
https://www.drupal8.eerr.org.uk/

I wonder if someone can help me out, I am not good with CSS and HTML so any advice welcome.

Thanks
Mark

EDIT

I am really hoping someone can help me edit the existing code not just send me a link to creating dropdown menus in stand-alone code.

The existing code seems to be generated in the following .twig file (Again I have no experience in developing in this)

themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/navigation/menu--main.html.twig

'''

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Bootstrap Barrio's override to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *   - is_expanded: TRUE if the link has visible children within the current
 *     menu tree.
 *   - is_collapsed: TRUE if the link has children within the current menu tree
 *     that are not currently visible.
 *   - in_active_trail: TRUE if the link is in the active trail.
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('nav navbar-nav') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          menu_level ? 'dropdown-item' : 'nav-item',
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
          item.below ? 'dropdown',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {%
          set link_classes = [
            not menu_level ? 'nav-link',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
            item.below ? 'dropdown-toggle',
            item.url.getOption('attributes').class ? item.url.getOption('attributes').class | join(' '),
            'nav-link-' ~ item.url.toString() | clean_class,
          ]
        %}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ link(item.title, item.url, {'class': link_classes, 'data-toggle': 'dropdown', 'aria-expanded': 'false', 'aria-haspopup': 'true' }) }}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% else %}
          {{ link(item.title, item.url, {'class': link_classes}) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

'''

Comment: I see you have started with the barrio theme that is shipped with drupal. Most Drupal 8 themes do not support mouse hover on their menus because mouse hover is not supported on touch devices (mobiles) and the themes are created to support mobiles devices (responsive)

Comment: You could output 2 menus, one that supports hover and desktops that displays on larger breakpoints and one with touch for mobiles that displays on the smaller breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse over hover can be done with JavaScript.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Learn how to create a hoverable dropdown menu with CSS.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">This</a>
    <a href="#">Shows </a>
    <a href="#">On</a>
    <a href="#">HOVER</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the minimum code neeeded for it to work. You can see more styling on the source.

Comment: I like the code. I was curious, why does the drop down work on the right side of the button and as far as to the right side of the screen? Is this an emulator error or is that how CSS treats the situation?

Comment: a tag is with the attribute display: block. Displays an element as a block element (like <p>). It starts on a new line, and takes up the whole width

Comment: Thank you. I write CSS differently than most so the behavior is different. I would have to force it to extend out to the other side of the screen with additional JS.

Comment: This is useful but I don't think it will help me much.  I can see Drupal is using a .twig file with the following code and I have no idea how to update it to include the above.  Thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `hover` is not mobile friendly.

This is just an advice ; there's no `hover` event on mobiles and touch pads. So if your website might be used on these devices, you should either keep `click` or implement the `touch` event.

Comment: you can use the `:tapped` selector instead (I think)